# Deploying Java Webapp to Cloud Foundry produces Pool Empty error

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, cloud-foundry, jhipster

Using JHipster with Java 1.8 and deploying to Cloud Foundry with the java [build pack from cloudfoundry](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/java-buildpack), running into an issue with connection pool sizes. I don't set it at the application level currently, and figure it's coming from the build pack. How do I increase the JDBC connection Pool size.

**Additional Details**:
I have logged this as an issue on the [jhipster-generator repo issues](https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/1054).

```
    Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: unable to obtain isolated JDBC connection
2015-01-29T13:42:24.95-0600 [App/0] OUT [ERROR] org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - [jibberish] Timeout: Pool empty. Unable to fetch a connection in 30 seconds, none available[size:4; busy:4; idle:0; lastwait:30000].
```

Comment: What database are you using?  Can you post some more information about how you are connecting to your DB?

Comment: The error message is saying that you're using all of the connections in the pool.  You've got 4 max connections, 4 of which are busy (i.e. in use) and 0 idle.  The pool is going on to say it waited for 30 seconds, but there were still no free connections.  What's the app doing?  Is that expected behavior?  As to why it's at 4, how many connections do you have to your provider?  Some of the free tier services only give you four connections.

Comment: The app was a simple CRUD app and the issue was around table type GenerationType.TABLE from early versions of the JHipster generator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Early generations of the JHipster Generator used GenerationType.TABLE for creating entities in the application.  Once this was changed to GenerationType.AUTO with updating the Liquibase schema's to  autoIncrement="true" then the issue was relieved and the application performs at reasonable expectations.

Here's the related code:

BAD:

```
/**
 * A EntityExample.
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "T_ENTITYEXAMPLE")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
public class EntityExample implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE)
    private Long id;
```

WORKS:

```
/**
 * A EntityExample.
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "T_ENTITYEXAMPLE")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
public class EntityExample implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
```

The updated XML (liquibase/changelog/timestamp_added_entity_EntityExample.xml)

```
<column name="id" type="bigint" autoIncrement="true">
    <constraints primaryKey="true" nullable="false"/>
</column>
```